# Задержка программы

Tags: c#, visual-basic

Я кликаю на `picturebox` и в него загружается изображение, дальше я кликаю по другому `picturebox` и если они одинаковые то они исчезаю. Я написал программу, но 
у меня не показывает вторую картинку и игрок не видит какая картинка открылась второй мне нужно сделать задержку, но не знаю как.
`Thread.Sleep(100);` не помогает.

Comment: самый простой (я не говорю правильный) - при клике на картинке показать ее и запустить таймер. А вот в обработчике таймера уже проверить и удалить картинки.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep(100);` - не помогает, потому-что здесь 100 - это 100 мс, т.е. 1/10 секунды. Увеличьте это значение, остановка будет больше